# Optimize Javascript code

Tags: javascript, optimization

I please any way to optimize & compress that js code

```
$("document").ready(function($) {
        var num = $('#menu').offset().top;
        var num2 = $('#HTML2').offset().top;
        var nav = $('#menu');
        var nav2 = $('#HTML2');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num) {
                nav.addClass("menu-scroll");
            } else {
                nav.removeClass("menu-scroll");
            }
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > num2) {
                nav2.addClass("html2fixs");
            } else {
                nav2.removeClass("html2fixs");
            }
        });
    $('#BackToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},300);
        return false;
    });
});
```

and please any tips on how to accelerate all JavaScript code in my site?

Comment: Unless you have a specific problem this sort of thing is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @charlietfl Don't recommend generally low-quality questions to another site. Only suggest migration when it would actually be acceptable for that site, all rules about clarity included.

Comment: get nav/nav2 first, then num/num2 from nav/nav2 - in general, try to use jquery as little as possible ... this suggestion removes two jquery calls, which could save  a few nanoseconds

Comment: Did you measure it? If so, what did you identify as the bottleneck? If you did not, then do so, and edit the question.

Comment: @Kroltan where does this not fit into the criteria? Seems to match each checklist item in code review help about what is on topic

Comment: @charlietfl It also matches the equivalent example of a "poor question" on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask (first yellow quote), discounting flair (e.g. thanks, emoticons) (which should also not be present)

Comment: @charlietfl In short: bad title, no context, no research.

Comment: @Kroltan Well all I did was tell OP there was an option. Not my job to act as a moderator and clean the question up for them. Of course they are subject to that site's guidelines. And there was no *"recommendation for migration"* .. simply a link for an alternate resource. And the word *"research"* doesn't even appear in the whole  "how to ask" page there

Comment: @charlietfl note *recommendation*, not *flag*. I did not suggest you wanted to take moderative action towards moving it. But only pointed out the facts expressed in [this meta.CR post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a JQuery function called `toggleScript`, that will make your code shorter. Also it would be better to call all your variables not only `num1` and `num2` in order to make your code more readable. When you saved an element into a variable - you don't have to call `${}` one more time, use the variable instead.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
    var menu = $('#menu'); //nav
    var html2 = $('#HTML2'); //nav2

    var menuOffsetTop = menu.offset().top; //num
    var html2OffsetTop = html2.offset().top; //num2


    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var w = $(this);

        menu.toggleClass('menu-scroll' , (w.scrollTop() > menuOffsetTop) );
        /* 
        The same as
        if (w.scrollTop() > menuOffsetTop) {
            menu.addClass('menu-scroll') ;  
        } else {
            menu.removeClass('menu-scroll');
        }
        */
        html2.toggleClass('html2fixs' , (w.scrollTop() > html2OffsetTop) );
    });

    $('#BackToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},300);
    });
});
```

Comment: ok thanks you so much .. & good luck guys :)